# Como generar un código ISBN automático en Python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, pycharm

Necesito generar un código ISBN en la forma xx-xxx-xxxx-x, x-xxx-xx-xxxxx etc, pero debe tener 10 dígitos en total y estar separado por guiones, además debe cumplir la siguiente condición: "el resto de dividir esa suma por 11, debe dar cero. Por ejemplo, para el siguiente ISBN: 84-8181-227-7 se comprueba que:  10*8+9*4+8*8+7*1+6*8+5*1+4*2+3*2+2*7+7 = 275 y al dividir 275 por 11 vemos que el resto es 0. Lo que nos indica que es un ISBN válido (275 % 11 = 0)."
Pensaba utlizar un ciclo for para generarlos y controlar que no se repitan y se cumpla la condición. Todo esto en Python.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque aquí no se hacen tareas.

Comment: **¿Qué has intentado?** Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El International Standard Book Number (ISBN) es un identificador numérico de libros comerciales que pretende ser único. Los editores compran ISBN de una filial de la Agencia Internacional de ISBN. Se asigna un ISBN a cada edición y variación (excepto reimpresiones) de un libro. Por ejemplo, un libro electrónico, un libro de bolsillo y una edición de tapa dura del mismo libro tendrían cada uno un ISBN diferente. El ISBN tiene 13 dígitos si se asigna a partir del 1 de enero de 2007, y 10 dígitos si se asigna antes de 2007. El método de asignación de un ISBN se basa en la nación y varía de un país a otro, a menudo según el tamaño de la industria editorial. dentro de un país.

### Generador de ISBN

Este script te permitirá generar los primeros 10 dígitos de válidos ISBN.

```
import csv
from random import randint
from multiprocessing import Pool


def isValidISBN(isbn):

    # check for length
    if len(isbn) != 10:
        return False

    formatted_num = isbn.replace("-", "")

    """
    Computing weighted sum
    of first 9 digits
    """
    checksum = 0
    for i in range(9):
        digit = int(formatted_num[i])
        checksum += digit * (10 - i)

    """
    If last digit is 'X', add
    10 to sum, else add its value.
    """
    last = formatted_num[-1]
    checksum += 10 if last == 'X' else int(last)
    """
    Return true if weighted sum of
    digits is divisible by 11
    """
    return (checksum % 11 == 0)


def split_range(range_, n):
    div = range_//n
    res = [[0, div]]
    last_div = div
    for i in range(2, n):
        res.append([last_div, div*i])
        last_div = div*i
    return res


def multiprocess(limits=[]):
    start = limits[0]
    stop = limits[1]
    isbn_list = []
    for i in range(start, stop):
        isbn = str(i)
        isbn_ = "0"*(10 - len(isbn)) + isbn
        isbn_X = "0"*(9 - len(isbn)) + isbn + "X"
        if isValidISBN(isbn_):
            isbn_list.append(isbn_)
        if isValidISBN(isbn_X):
            isbn_list.append(isbn_X)
    return isbn_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    isbns = []
    isbn_list = []

    args = split_range(1000000, 9)
    p = Pool(9)
    isbns += p.map(multiprocess, [*args])
    for i in isbns:
        isbn_list.extend(i)

    csvfile = "./isbns.txt"
    with open(csvfile, 'w') as resultFile:
        for i in isbn_list:
            resultFile.write(i + ",")
```

Comment: Aunque se agradece la intención, procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad o en donde el OP (autor de la pregunta) no demuestre esfuerzo en haber intentado resolver lo que plantea. Lee [answer].